# why error is displayed with find function

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web, beautifulsoup

[web scrapping python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Uf5.png)
why the parameters of find function is showing error.

I was expecting it to print data in tag `<span></span>`
for example:

```
<span>APPLE iPhone 14 (Midnight, 128 GB)</span>
```

I want to extract APPLE iPhone 14 (Midnight, 128 GB) from the HTML code.
link of the website is: https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-14-midnight-128-gb/p/itm9e6293c322a84
code:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-14-midnight-128-gb/p/itm9e6293c322a84"

r=requests.get(url)

html_content=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(html_content,"html.parser").prettify()

name=soup.find("span",{"class":"B_NuCI"})

print(name)
```

error:

```
C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    name=soup.find("span",{"class":"B_NuCI"})
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve]  On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.
Thanks

Comment: Please copy your code instead of pictures so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the [`.prettify()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing), because it will convert your `BeautifulSoup` object into a string, so you no longer be able to access the info the way you try to do.

> The goal of prettify() is to help you visually understand the structure of the documents you work with.

*If you just wanna see pretty structure use it only this way `print(soup.prettify())` not on `BeautifulSoup(...).prettify()`*

##### Example

```
import requests
soup = BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-14-midnight-128-gb/p/itm9e6293c322a84').text
        )

soup.find('span', class_='B_NuCI').text
```

##### Output

```
APPLE iPhone 14 (Midnight, 128 GB)
```

Comment: but i couldn't udestand why prettyfy() is removed

Comment: You do not need it and it will convert to string and will be no more an object.